# Что значит text[] в postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, типы-данных

В поисках ответа на свои вопросы я наткнулся на такой фрагмент кода `CREATE TABLE table_name(text TEXT[]);`. И я бы хотел узнать по подробнее что значит `TEXT[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тип данных [массив](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/arrays), в данном случае массив строк.

Может хранить ноль или больше строк, поддерживает операции сравнения, получения по индексу, проверку вхождения и [другие](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/functions-array), которые вы обычно ожидаете получить от массива. Для операций вхождения и пересечения массивов могут быть использованы индексы.